# Assembly cmp SIGSEV segmentation fault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att

Im trying code in Assembly, and i have a little problem. My program stoped with SIGSEV segmentation fault. GDB stops at

> cmpb %bl, 0x41

in check_loop. Program just check every single char and modify it when it is lowercase, great or other

```
.bss
.comm textin, 512
.comm textout, 512

.text

.global main
main:

movq $SYSREAD, %rax
movq $STDIN, %rdi
movq $textin, %rsi
movq $BUFLEN, %rdx
syscall

CALL changing

changing:
movl $0, %edi
jmp check_loop

check_loop:
movb textin(,%edi,1),%bl
cmpb %bl, 0x41
jl other
cmpb %bl, 0x5A
jl great
cmpb %bl, 0x61
jl other
cmpb %bl, 0x7a
jg other

lower:
addb %bl, 0x06
movb %bl,textout(,%edi,1)
jmp isEND

great:
addb %bl, 0x08
movb %bl,textout(,%edi,1)
jmp isEND

other:
movb %bl,textout(,%edi,1)
jmp isEND

isEND:
incl %edi
cmpl %eax, %edi
jl check_loop
ret
```

Comment: at&t syntax requires `$` prefix on immediate numbers or else they will be treated as addresses which will then fault.